# Can't close a JSX. Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I just want to try out a Hello World of an UI framework for React, called CoreUI. 
But it says I got my JSX wrong and unclosed. But I already closed all } and ), so please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    // Required meta tags
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    // CoreUI CSS
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.0.0-rc.0/dist/css/coreui.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>CoreUI<title/>
    <head/>
    <body class="c-app">
    <h1>Hello, world!<h1/>

    // Optional JavaScript
    // Popper.js first, then CoreUI JS
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-L2pyEeut/H3mtgCBaUNw7KWzp5n9&#43;4pDQiExs933/5QfaTh8YStYFFkOzSoXjlTb" crossorigin="anonymous"><script/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.0.0-rc.0/dist/js/coreui.min.js"><script/>
    <body/>
    <html/>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: You need to self close the `meta` tags. The closing tag for `head`, `body`, `html`, `h1`, `title` are also wrong. A self closing tag looks like this: `<tag />`, a closing tag paired with an opening tag looks like this: `<tag></tag>`.

Comment: looks like your closing tags are wrong, e.g. `<html/>` should be  `</html>`

Comment: @BrianThompson Is space on <tag /> important on closing the tag?

Comment: No. Its optional. I just think its more readable

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use regular JavaScript `//` comments in JSX. Remove those and add them like this:

```
<head>
{/* Required meta tags */}
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

An editor like VSCode will do this automatically.

And the closing tags also need fixing:

```
<h1>Hello, world!<h1/> => <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your closing tags are not proper. it should be

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => { 
return (<html lang="en">
<head>
// Required meta tags
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

// CoreUI CSS
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.0.0-rc.0/dist/css/coreui.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<title>CoreUI</title>
</head>
<body class="c-app">
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

// Optional JavaScript
// Popper.js first, then CoreUI JS
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-L2pyEeut/H3mtgCBaUNw7KWzp5n9&#43;4pDQiExs933/5QfaTh8YStYFFkOzSoXjlTb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.0.0-rc.0/dist/js/coreui.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
); 

};


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags are not closed. Try this:

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    // Required meta tags
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    // CoreUI CSS
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.0.0-rc.0/dist/css/coreui.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>CoreUI<title/>
    <head/>
    <body class="c-app">
    <h1>Hello, world!<h1/>

    // Optional JavaScript
    // Popper.js first, then CoreUI JS
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-L2pyEeut/H3mtgCBaUNw7KWzp5n9&#43;4pDQiExs933/5QfaTh8YStYFFkOzSoXjlTb" crossorigin="anonymous"><script/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.0.0-rc.0/dist/js/coreui.min.js"><script/>
    <body/>
    <html/>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to self close the meta tags. Secondaly other closing tags are also not proper as they should be like this `</html` instead of ` .

Below is the corrected code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => { 
return (

<html lang="en">
 <head>
 // Required meta tags
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

 // CoreUI CSS
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.0.0-rc.0/dist/css/coreui.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />

 <title>CoreUI</title>
 </head>
  <body class="c-app">
   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

   // Optional JavaScript
   // Popper.js first, then CoreUI JS
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-L2pyEeut/H3mtgCBaUNw7KWzp5n9&#43;4pDQiExs933/5QfaTh8YStYFFkOzSoXjlTb" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.0.0-rc.0/dist/js/coreui.min.js">
   </script>
  </body>
 </html>
); 

};


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, document.querySelector('#root')
);
```